# Problema com .find()

Tags: jquery

Estou a tentar procurar um `li` com uma certa class (`selected`), no entanto, não tenho conseguido encontrar o `id` dela.

Eis o código

```
var slide_act = $(".bull").find("selected").attr("id");
console.log(slide_act);
```

Na consola aparece `undefined` sempre que executo a função de `click`. Alguma explicação?

**Código Complementar**

```
<ul class="bullets">
  <li class="bull selected" id="slide1"></li>
  <li class="bull" id="slide2"></li>
  <li class="bull" id="slide3"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Posta o html para conseguirmos te ajudar

Comment: @CaiqueRomero Desculpe, editado.

Comment: porque vc n procura logo pela class `selected` assim : `var slide_act = $(".selected").attr("id");` ?

Comment: @ViniciusShiguemori Isso resulta como resposta temporária, mas essa class pode estar associada a outras coisas, por isso queria só selecionar as que também tivessem a class `.bull`

Comment: Também faltou um ponto `.` no `find("selected")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente pegar o atributo "id" do elemento que possuir tanto a classe "bull" quanto a classe "selected":

```
var slide_act = $(".bull.selected").attr("id");
```

[Seletor de classe Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Veja exemplo funcionando:

```js
var slide_act = $(".bull.selected").attr("id");
console.log(slide_act);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="bullets">
  <li class="bull selected" id="slide1"></li>
  <li class="bull" id="slide2"></li>
  <li class="bull" id="slide3"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Funcionou! Eu tentei com o espaço no meio, assim: `$(".bull .selected")` mas não deu, poderia explicar?

Comment: A syntax correta é sem o espaço, adicionei a documentação na resposta. https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: É que separado ele tenta achar o descendente da class bull que tenha a class selected seria por exemplo : `<ul class="bullets"><li class="bull" id="slide1"><ul class="selected" id="teste"></ul></li></ul>`, ja quando está junto ele procura os elementos que possui ambas as classes